ng version does not show the version 17
I have installed Angular globally on my Linux Fedora machine with sudo npm i -g @angular/cli@17.0.3. However, when I run ng version, it prints the following:

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 14.2.1
Node: 20.17.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 10.8.1 
OS: linux x64

Angular: undefined
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1402.1
@angular-devkit/core         14.2.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   14.2.1
@angular/cli                 14.2.1
@schematics/angular          14.2.1
    
Warning: The current version of Node (20.17.0) is not supported by Angular.

The version in the output is not 17.0.3 as desired. Why?
I tried to uninstall it using npm uninstall -g @angular/cli and then install again (following the answer on this question), but that did not help, it still prints the Angular version as 14.2.1.

What do you get by running which ng?

/usr/local/bin/ng

That's the only instance of ng you have? If you call that binary directly is that the one that's 14.2.1?

What's the output of npm outdated or npm -g outdated ? Do you have any warning/error when you try sudo npm i -g @angular/cli@17.0.3 ?

npm outdated prints the version of @angular/cli as 14.2.1, while npm -g outdated prints it as 17.0.3.

Uninstall Angular CLI Completely:
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

Clear NPM Cache:
npm cache clean --force

Reinstall the Desired Version: Now, reinstall the desired version of Angular CLI:
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@17.0.3


Step 1: Completely Remove All Angular CLI Versions
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

sudo npm cache clean --force

npm ls @angular/cli

npm uninstall @angular/cli

Step 2: Verify Removal
ng version

Step 3: Reinstall the Desired Version Globally
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@17.0.3
ng version

This should now display Angular CLI 17.0.3.

When the global CLI is being run in a directory that has a local version of the CLI installed it will defer execution to the local version.
If you run this in a directory that does not contain @angular/cli as a directory I presume you will see your expected globally installed version.
